# Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-xp, usb

So last night my OS(Windows) died on me, my bootmgr went missing(corrupt i guess) and i could not load into windows. I used my brothers computer to download Ubuntu as a temp OS until i get my hands on a windows ulimate ISO.

I began to like Ubuntu so i thought i may stick with it, until it started crashing on me.

Ubuntu itself has crashed atleast 4 times within me typing this question(required me to actually restart my computer and retype this). Now, my computer did not crash as I could still move my mouse but nothing on the os OR the os itself would respond.

Anyway, i have decided to go back to windows now as i did not have half as many problems with windows that i have with ubuntu.

Now, I got my hands on the official windows 7 ultimate from the Microsoft website and used Universal USB installer to make my usb a bootable installer. Now, this worked perfectly for Ubuntu, it ran and installed flawlessly.

On the other hand, when doing this with windows 7 ultimate, it just gets stuck on "Windows is loading files"(It fills up, then freezes). I have read up about this problem and have come to the conclution that my RAM is not working as it should be.

So, as my friend suggested I attempted to try Windows Server 2012 R2, I get passed the "Files are loading" part, but then get left with a completely black screen. No cursor or anything like that.

I have even attempted to run a Windows XP iso which completely failed(Didnt even start up the installer).

If i forgot to mention, i am doing this all from my USB.

Should I just give up on this computer or is there any way i can bring it back from the dead without replacing its RAM?

Thanks!

Comment: [WinUSB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/489546/installing-winusb-on-ubuntu-14-04/489556#489556) is a application for creating a Windows bootable USB flash drive that works in Windows and also in Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel I will attempt an install of win 7 ultimate with it now, will report back.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you got Ubuntu working properly, so that indicates that you don't have hardware issues.  You described your original problem as a corrupted bootmgr, which is fixable.  You are having problems in general loading any OS via USB, which points to a common denominator (which you fixed for Ubuntu).  This is way to complex for a single question.  Pick one issue (at a time), write a focused question on that, provide basic information about your hardware & procedures, and that would lend itself to being able to help you within the scope of this site.

Comment: @fixer1234 Indeed, i was able to install ubuntu from USB, but not any windows iso so far.

Comment: You have quite a collection of Windows ISOs.  I'm assuming you got them from a reliable source (Digital River), so your problem is not that you are trying to install crud.  You're aware that you need a license key for the Windows you install or it is likely to stop working (and you shouldn't rely on anything from an unofficial source)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes. All the windows ISO's I got from the Microsoft website(Either provided directly by them, or a comment of someone with rep.) and the ubuntu iso i got from the official ubuntu website.

The main reason i tried win server and XP is to see if it was an ISO problem or a problem my side, not to be a permanent OS.

Comment: @karel I keep getting "Device is not a special block" report back from WinUSB.

Comment: By USB do you mean a flash drive?  If you have a DVD drive, that would be a much simpler installation route and would eliminate a bunch of potential side issues associated with doing it from a flash drive.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, its a kingston. Also, I would burn it to a disc but I do not have a 3-6gb disc nor can I get my hands on one any time soon, unfortunately.

Comment: Any ideas? im running out here...

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a new usb and running setup again if it doesn't work, you should just give up if you don't want to replace parts or get it looked at.